# How to loop vertical carousel on scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, addeventlistener

Once the bottom of the `div` is reached, I would like to scroll back to the top of the images sequence using plain Javascript.

I want to set an infinite scroll that loops the images every time the user scrolls to last image.

I have no idea how to do that but here is what I have tried. I do not get any error messages so I am not sure what I am doing wrong

thank you for your help.

```js
var Right = {
  width: window.imageWidth / 2,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0
};

let counter = 1;
var rightImages = right.getElementsByTagName('img')


function rotateForward() {
  var right = Right.right = document.getElementById("right"),
    children = rightImages,
    firstChild = rightImages[0],
    lastChild = rightImages[rightImages.length - 1];
  var lastChildPos = lastChild.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var rightPosition = window.innerHeight;
  if (lastChildPos >= rightPosition) {
    height = right.children
    counter = rightImages.length - 2;
  }
}

right.addEventListener('scroll', rotateForward());
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(254, 238, 228);
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-height: auto;
}

#right {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#right a img {
  height: 92.5vh;
  width: 50vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="right">
  <a href="project6" id="lastClone"><img src="https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/binaries/content/gallery/metofficegovuk/hero-images/weather/cloud/cumulus-cloud.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="project1"><img src="https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/product/Screenshot/StoreUltraDynamicSkyscreenshot1-1920x1080-f5d2cdb93df61507a2e584354de459ca-1920x1080-a431ce7a2eb0a4eb720b25de2ba0aca3.png" /></a>
  <a href="project2"><img src="https://www.rolls-roycemotorcars.com/content/dam/rrmc/marketUK/rollsroycemotorcars_com/2-6-4-under-the-stars/page-properties/rolls-royce-under-the-stars-hero-d.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="project3"><img src="https://www.citynews1130.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/sites/9/2018/05/27/iStock-697020460.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="project4"><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/GlbCESxjIY2pjzV9B9hwoySVG6sJRErg_ylUlHt2XUm2PWhDpDWBZMOkUL0s4wMImdG8LP8Xm6KfB3KPVddCiBGSJO9psgZ13DkPSjNUngDg1iyGkQvxOQXdLDp1PXyF9b-lVSQ" /></a>
  <a href="project5"><img src="https://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2019/07/moon_seen_from_space_station/19494773-1-eng-GB/Moon_seen_from_Space_Station_pillars.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="project6"><img src="https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/binaries/content/gallery/metofficegovuk/hero-images/weather/cloud/cumulus-cloud.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="project1" id="firstClone"><img src="https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/product/Screenshot/StoreUltraDynamicSkyscreenshot1-1920x1080-f5d2cdb93df61507a2e584354de459ca-1920x1080-a431ce7a2eb0a4eb720b25de2ba0aca3.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how to trigger functions based on location of scroller position, but this  might help providing base for going to the top:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is a scroll event example:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (shouldScrollTop(window.scrollY)) window.scrollTo(someX, someY);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

In order to make this work, you will need to implement `shouldScrollTop`, which would get a numeric value for `scrollY` and will return whether a scroll is needed, you also need to know where you want to scroll to, so you will need to define `someX` and `someY` as well.

Comment: hey sorry what I am trying to do is create a kind of infinite scroll that loops the images forever

Comment: @caíd I see. You will need to load some items then besides calling ```window.scrollTo```